# What does the full stop do when assigned to a formula in r? In the parameter of lm

Tags: r, lm

I am a C# developer, new to R, trying to understand the code line

```
fit <- lm(quality ~ .,wine)
```

I get that this creates a list called fit and that

quality ~ .

must somehow instantiate an object of class "formula" for use within the lm function.

from typing

```
help("~")
```

into the R Studio Console, I see that

> Tilde is used to separate the left- and right-hand sides in a model
> formula.
> **Usage** y ~ model 
> **Arguments** y, model     symbolic expressions.
> **Details** The left-hand side is optional, and one-sided formulae are
> used in some contexts.
>
> A formula has mode call. It can be subsetted by [[: the components are
> ~, the left-hand side (if present) and the right-hand side in that
> order.

But I am not told what the left and right sides in a model formula are.

What does the following mean?

```
quality ~ .
```

What is meant by

> the left and right hand sides

of a model formula?

Comment: Thanks, I added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is concerned with `formula`, we can check the documentation of `?formula`

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see terms.formula. In the context of update.formula, only, it means ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to enlarge the Help Window in RStudio? I am having trouble locating the update context

Comment: Ah, where are you typing "?formula " ?

Comment: @KirstenGreed it is in the console

Comment: @KirstenGreed I generally use R console.  Just to show where you could use it in Rstudio, I updated with a screenshot

Comment: Thanks. RConsole looks very similar to RStudio

Comment: @KirstenGreed that is Rstudio.  I meant that I don't generally use Rstudio